# cache.match() returns response but no headers

Tags: javascript, caching, cachestorage

When I'm performing a `cache.match(url)` I successfully get a response. But the response the cache is giving me has no headers and I can't understand why.

When I'm looking into the developer tools and the cache storage, I can see the headers that are stored with the corresponding request.

Does anyone know, why I cannot get the headers?

Comment: I realize this is four years old but I'm hitting the same issue and wondering if it's something to do with `type: cors` but I'm not sure.

If you've solved this or had any additional insight I'd be interested. Thanks!

Comment: Actually it turned out my issue was related specifically to my AWS S3 bucket's CORS policies.